# Is there a way to use workflow to manage downloads of pictures in a picture library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, picture-library, image, download

We are looking to create a library of images for everyone in the organisation to be able to see and use, but we don't want people just downloading them to their local drives, we want to know what it is going to be used for, etc. Any suggestions for an easy way to make people basically fill out a form which requires approval from a specific individual and only then permits download? Thank you.

Comment: When you have an image available for a preview, any slightly advanced user can open and/or save it from there. If this causes problems, you'd need consider either thumbnails or watermarks for the pictures, which makes the implementation significantly more complicated.